# Closed sites show up in the Moderator migration dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderator-tools

Moderators can choose closed sites as migration destinations

[image: screen shot]

([Both](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy) [sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) are closed)

Now I don't know what happens if we go through with this migration, but it would probably lead to the post being lost in some vortex of doom. Could this be fixed?

Edit: OK, I tried it with a dummy post. The migration is immediately rejected (i.e, the close reason is "off topic", and our good friend Community♦ locks it). Not too bad, but it's still a bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well that's not supposed to happen, it'll be fixed in the next build.